# Can someone please provide the method of worship for Manasa Devi?

Tags: worship, devi, idols

I have read that Manasa Devi is worshipped using a cactus, tree branch or snake idol. Is this correct? Can someone please provide more information regarding the correct procedure to worship Manasa Devi?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen quite often the snake idols for Manasa Devi. Then normal aarti/puja is carried out with those.

This article has excerpts from a book on Hindu goddesses and includes some (brief) info on that :

https://hinduaesthetic.medium.com/goddess-m%C4%81nasa-cb84c3ea1222

(It's a site link with published book segments, not sure if this is acceptable for answer on HSE, plz remove/delete if not.)

I'm drawn to the myths and folklore around Goddess Manasa, with her father (alternate stories giving MahaDev or Rishi Kashyp), stepmother Parvati, son Asthik, husband Jaratkaru, the Behula-Lakhinder story. Fighting spirit to prevail against the odds. Great to see some different discussion topics of her here.

Comment: link-only answers, in general, are not accepted as answers on any stack site.

Comment: @hanugm No probs, I understand, plz remove/delete the above if that would be best. I'm looking around for more scripture citations to improve the answer but not coming up with much.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Replying to the community bot above to say : Hi, pujas and that type of personal experience aren't proper proof here and outside of those, I unfortunately don't have documentation/citations at this time ? So plz feel free to change or erase the answer if shouldn't be up, that is fine with me, no worries. Thx :D

Answer (score 0):

The method of worshipping Devi Manasa is in [Devi Bhagwatam](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57361.htmlDe)

> 1-30. Nārāyaṇa said :-- O Nārada! I will now speak of the Dhyānam and the method of worship of Śrī Devī Manasā, as stated in the Sāma Veda. Hear. “I meditate on the Devī Manasā, Whose colour is fair like that of the white champaka flower, whose body is decked all over with jewel ornaments, whose clothing is purified by fire, whose sacred thread is the Nāgas (serpent), who is full of wisdom, who is the foremost of great Jñanins, who is the Presiding deity of the Siddhas, Who Herself is a Siddha and who bestows Siddhis to all.” O Muni! **Thus meditating on Her, one should present Her, flowers, scents, ornaments, offerings of food and various other articles, pronouncing the principal Seed Mantra.**

You can go through the link for complete procedure.